# Deferred loading of Google map api using jquery with fail callback

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps JS API for my web application and I want to load this api asynchronously i.e deffered loading.
I am using [this code](https://gist.github.com/gbakernet/828536). I added a fail callback in this code but this callback is not getting executed.

Comment: Instead of linking to someone else's code, show us **your** code, especially your callback

Comment: $.when(loadMapsApi(3, "", ""))
                    .then(function () {
                        !!google.maps; // true
                    }).done(function () {console.log('Map loaded successfuly');}).fail(function () {console.log('Map loading failed');})

Comment: Don't add it as a comment, update your question to include that code

Comment: Looks to me like you are missing the required `sensor` parameter in your fallback section.